# CutePDF Writer Via Powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, cmd, printing, adobe

I have a need to compress PDFs by printing with CutePDF Writer.
I have come up with this very simple example using Powershell...

```
$pdf = 'c:\path\to\pdf.pdf'
Start-Process -FilePath $pdf | Out-Printer -Name 'CutePDF Writer'
```

This does half of the job, the only problem is when it's done printing it opens the file in Adobe Reader to 'save file as'. I can't seem to find a way to either pass commands through Powershell to do this, or save the file using the open Adobe Reader via cmd line.

Is this possible, or maybe a different solution I didn't come up with?

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath $pdf` doesn't send anything through the pipeline; instead, it asynchronously opens the PDF file with the application registered for `.pdf` files.

Comment: I have no experience with CutePDF, but the way `Out-Printer` generally works is by receiving the actual _data_ to print, not the path of a  file or a file-info object.

Comment: you might be able to use `out-printer`

Comment: @mklement0 Hmm that's odd. When I save the file manual, once opened from my script, the file is compressed as I would expect. But I'll look for another method that may better fits my needs, thanks for the input.